# okHttp3 JVM Crash

Tags: java, okhttp, freebsd, coredump

I am working with an SDK which internally uses okHttp3 v3.14.7,
It is internally creating multiple instances of ConnectionPool() and OkHTTPClient(),

Not for each call but on the random stage I get a core dump,
Below is the backtrace file

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 11488  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000804578fff [0x0000000804578f80+0x7f]
J 10954 C1 java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BIII)I (290 bytes) @ 0x00000008043b3f5c [0x00000008043b3800+0x75c]
J 10953 C1 java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BII)I (15 bytes) @ 0x00000008043b7f64 [0x00000008043b7e00+0x164]
J 11133 C1 sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;[BII)I (137 bytes) @ 0x00000008044890dc [0x0000000804488f60+0x17c]
J 12140 C1 sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V (127 bytes) @ 0x00000008047d687c [0x00000008047d6720+0x15c]
J 13279 C1 sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V (872 bytes) @ 0x0000000804a6e31c [0x0000000804a6dec0+0x45c]
J 14563 C1 sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read([BII)I (129 bytes) @ 0x0000000804ee94b4 [0x0000000804ee8bc0+0x8f4]
J 15367 C1 okio.Okio$2.read(Lokio/Buffer;J)J (154 bytes) @ 0x0000000803f893ac [0x0000000803f88f60+0x44c]
J 15366 C1 okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(Lokio/Buffer;J)J (68 bytes) @ 0x0000000803f76e44 [0x0000000803f76c20+0x224]
J 11589 C1 okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(BJJ)J (152 bytes) @ 0x00000008045cd1cc [0x00000008045ccde0+0x3ec]
J 11135 C1 okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(J)Ljava/lang/String; (235 bytes) @ 0x00000008044936bc [0x00000008044934a0+0x21c]
J 11134 C1 okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine()Ljava/lang/String; (30 bytes) @ 0x0000000804488a4c [0x0000000804488900+0x14c]
j  okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Z)Lokhttp3/Response$Builder;+47
j  okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Z)Lokhttp3/Response$Builder;+5
j  okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(Lokhttp3/Interceptor$Chain;)Lokhttp3/Response;+226
J 11815 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Transmitter;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Exchange;)Lokhttp3/Response; (378 bytes) @ 0x00000008046c4b3c [0x00000008046c41e0+0x95c]
j  okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(Lokhttp3/Interceptor$Chain;)Lokhttp3/Response;+51
J 11815 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Transmitter;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Exchange;)Lokhttp3/Response; (378 bytes) @ 0x00000008046c4b3c [0x00000008046c41e0+0x95c]
J 12440 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;)Lokhttp3/Response; (14 bytes) @ 0x000000080492e984 [0x000000080492e840+0x144]
j  okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(Lokhttp3/Interceptor$Chain;)Lokhttp3/Response;+192
J 11815 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Transmitter;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Exchange;)Lokhttp3/Response; (378 bytes) @ 0x00000008046c4b3c [0x00000008046c41e0+0x95c]
J 12440 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;)Lokhttp3/Response; (14 bytes) @ 0x000000080492e984 [0x000000080492e840+0x144]
j  okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(Lokhttp3/Interceptor$Chain;)Lokhttp3/Response;+238
J 11815 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Transmitter;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Exchange;)Lokhttp3/Response; (378 bytes) @ 0x00000008046c4b3c [0x00000008046c41e0+0x95c]
j  okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(Lokhttp3/Interceptor$Chain;)Lokhttp3/Response;+56
J 11815 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Transmitter;Lokhttp3/internal/connection/Exchange;)Lokhttp3/Response; (378 bytes) @ 0x00000008046c4b3c [0x00000008046c41e0+0x95c]
J 12440 C1 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(Lokhttp3/Request;)Lokhttp3/Response; (14 bytes) @
```

Last native frame

```
C  [libc.so.7+0x7ee33]  free+0x1e3
```

Can creation on multiple okHttpClient object lead to core dump?

while running a similar program and creating multiple object of connectionPool() and okHTTPClient() there was only `OutOfMemoryException` but not a core dump

```
OS: FreeBSD 8 
JVM: OpenJDK 8 (8u265)
```

Comment: FreeBSD is a path less well traveled for the JVM

Comment: True, the same SDK works perfectly fine in Ubuntu 16.0, but leads to core dump in FreeBSD

Comment: Perhaps take to a dedicated FreeBSD forum?

Comment: still in a dilemma whether truly it's an OS related issue, or there is something which i am missing with respect to JVM

Comment: Perhaps because FreeBSD version 8 was end-of-life hundreds of years ago? (I might be exaggerating. It was five to 10 years ago depending on which .x version)